# I got your message just now

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

Let's say I just turned on my computer, opened email and there is an unread message from my friend there - he sent it to me a few hours ago. First of all, I want to tell him that I didn't answer because I got it just now:

> I **got** your message just now, sorry.

Would it be common, idiomatic phrase?

And isn't it ambiguous? The first meaning:

> I **received** your message just now, sorry. (this is the meaning I want to convey)

The second meaning:

> I **understood** your message just now, sorry.

(We say "I got it", "I didn't get it" meaning "I understood it", "I didn't understand it", right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just concerned with idiomatic conversational English, "I got your message just now, sorry," is acceptable and commonly used. The *context* makes it clear that it's *reception* of the message, not the *comprehension* of it, that you're discussing.

It might also be written, "Sorry, I just got your message," but that's no more or less likely to be used.

BTW, consider the word, "unionized," which has two completely different meanings in chemistry and in economics. The context makes clear which is intended, e.g. "FIAT is unionized," vs. "Argon is unionized."

Comment: I would say "I've only just seen your message".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's ambiguous, but I doubt many people would take *got* for *understood* in this context.  (In an actual message, there might be another sentence that makes the context clearer, such as *Before reflecting on it, I had thought that it meant...* or *I was unavailable because...).*

Certainly it's better to avoid ambiguity by preferring *receive* or *understand,* as the case may be, over *get.*